# Returning async data from method1 to method2 while having no influence on the script that fetches the async data in method1

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, methods

In TypeScript I try to call an external script [SPCalendarPro](https://github.com/samperrow/SPCalendarPro) in a private method that async fetches some data. The script is called as follows:

```
private _getSPCalendarPro() {
  const spcalpro: any = require('./spcalendarpro.js');
}
```

After calling the script I need to call the function as follows:

```
spcalpro.getCalendarEvents({
  listName: "StaffSchedule"
}).ready(function(data, obj) {
  if (obj.error) console.error( obj.error );
  console.table( data );
});
```

The complete method is as follows:

```
private _getSPCalendarPro() {
  const spcalpro: any = require('./spcalendarpro.js');

  return spcalpro.getCalendarEvents({
    listName: "StaffSchedule"
  }).ready(function(data, obj) {
    if (obj.error) console.error( obj.error );
    console.table( data );
    return obj;
  });
}
```

The script returns a data and obj variable, which I have to use in another method. However, when I call the above method from another function I get the .ready() function back as text. Leaving out the .ready() part returns me the fetched object, but with the data part empty. This is due to the fact that the data is fetched async and not yet resolved when the method is returned. The returned object consists of:

> listName:
> async:
> fields:
> userEnvData:
> callback:
> CamlQuery:
> data:

The method from which I call the _getSPCalendarPro method:

```
private _calendarData() {
  const calObj = this._getSPCalendarPro();
  const calObjData = calObj['data'];
  console.log(calObj);
  console.log(calObjData);
}
```

calObj is filled nicely, but calObjData is undefined. I've tried to use async / await and jquery deferred, but without luck. I couldn't find an answer on this particular subject either. Hope someone can help me on what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
I have tried to create a promise for _getSPCalendarPro, but I am not sure how to do this the right way since the external script is fetching the actual data.

```
private _getSPCalendarPro(): Promise<void> {
  const spcalpro: any = require('./spcalendarpro.js');

  const spcal = spcalpro.getCalendarEvents({
    listName: "StaffSchedule"
  }).ready(function(data, obj) {
    if (obj.error) console.error( obj.error );
    console.table( data );
    return obj;
  });

  return spcal().then((response) => {
    return response;
  })

}
```

**FINAL WORKING CODE**
Thanks to Yoshi.

```
export interface ISPCalendarPro {
  data: any;
}

private _getSPCalendarPro(): Promise<ISPCalendarPro> {
  const spcalpro: any = require('./spcalendarpro.js');


  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const spcal = spcalpro.getCalendarEvents({
      listName: "StaffSchedule"
    }).ready(function(data, obj) {
      obj.error
      ? reject(obj.error) // reject on error
      : resolve(obj);    // or resolve
    })
  })
}

private _calendarData() {
  this._getSPCalendarPro().then((calData) => {
    console.log(calData);
  });
}
```

Comment: Try dynamic import:  `import('./some_file.js').then(file=>console.log({file}))`

Comment: This leads me to the error "Expression expected.ts(1109)". I also wouldn't know how this would help me to wait in _calendarData to return the calObjData, care to elaborate?

Comment: You could return a promise from `_getSPCalendarPro` (either directly or via marking the method async). And then `await` or `.then` on this promise in `_calendarData`.

Comment: I've been thinking about that, but I am afraid I don't know how to get that to work. When I do private _getSPCalendarPro(): Promise <void> { } I have no idea how to return an actual response, since the external script is getting something for me..

Comment: I'll try to post an answer, but before: can you elaborate on this line: `const calObj = script._getSPCalendarPro();`   why `script.` here? Shouldn't it be `this`?

Comment: That's great. You're right, typo while copying into my question. Edited it, good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can return a promise and resolve it using the supplied ready callback.

Something like:

```
type Data = unknown; // you'll need to fill this in.

class Something
{
  private _getSPCalendarPro(): Promise<Data> {
    const spcalpro: any = require('./spcalendarpro.js');

    // return a promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // on ready
      spcalpro.getCalendarEvents({listName: "StaffSchedule"}).ready(function(data, obj) {
        obj.error
          ? reject(obj.error) // reject on error
          : resolve(data);    // or resolve
      });
    });
  }

  private async _calendarData() {
    try {
      // await the promise
      const data = await this._getSPCalendarPro();
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Instead of the private async _calendarData() { try catch } part I have used:
this._getSPCalendarPro().then((calData) => {
   console.log(calData);
});.
I've edited my question with my final code.

Comment: Of course you can do that. It's just preference I guess. ;)